# accessing values from unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map:

`unordered_map<string, list<string>> adj_list;`

how do I see if the list of strings `list<string>` contains a value?

I tried:

```
if(adj_list.find("find")) printf("value found");
```

but it gives me a conversion error.
How do I access the first string and the second list of strings in this `unordered_map`?
Clarifications: I have a value `"here"` that is the first string in the `adj_list`, I would like to find  `"find"` in the list of strings that belongs to `"here"`.

Comment: the term 'second position' has no meaning for an unordeded_map

Comment: I would help if you gave some input output examples.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the list of strings that comes after the ',' in the unordered_map<string, list<string>>

Comment: Edit your clarifications into the question, instead of as comments.

Comment: If your issue is to find element in `std::list`, why mentioning `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: @Jarod42, because I am trying to find a value in that list associated with the first string in the unordered_map

Comment: You succeed to find the `std::list<string>` associated to `"here"`? Providing minimal code would avoid us to guess your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the key you can do this:

```
auto l = adj_list.find("here"); // here we get the correct list
if(l != adj_list.end())
{
    if(std::find(l->second.begin(), l->second.end(),"find") != l->second.end())
    {
        printf("Found");
    }
}
```

You can do this if you don't know what the key to the correct `list<string>` in the map is:

```
for(auto it=adj_list.begin(); it != adj_list.end(); ++it)
{
    if(std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(),"find") != it->second.end())
    {
        printf("Found");
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<list>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> adj_list;
    std::list<std::string> l;
    l.emplace_back("find");

    adj_list.emplace("string", l);
    for (auto it = adj_list.begin(); it != adj_list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), "find") != it->second.end())
        {
            printf("Found");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP has a map of lists of strings. Wants to know if the second entry in the map, a list, has 'find' in it.

Comment: @bhristov, it tells me that  this data structure has no member named find. As in it does not recognize .find() method

Comment: @DenisShevchenko I updated my answer. You need to use std::find()

Comment: I tried that however now it tells me ``` no matching function for call to ‘find(std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator, const string&)’
           if(std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), n) != it->second.end())```

Comment: @DenisShevchenko the code ran on my system. I am not sure what could be causing this. I added the full code.

Comment: @bhristov, I implemented the full code you posted and it works. Thank you

Comment: @DenisShevchenko no problem. I am glad that I could help. Could you please mark this answer as the answer to your question?

Comment: You can even use *for range*: `for (auto& p : adj_list)`

Answer (score 2):

To find an element in `std::list`, you might use `std::find`:

```
std::unordered_map<string, list<string>> adj_list /* = ..*/;

auto it_umap = adl_list.find("here");
if (it_umap != adl_list.end())
{
    auto& words = it_umap->second;
    auto it = std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), "find");
    if (it != words.end()) { std::cout << "value found"; }
}
```

Comment: OP has a map of lists of strings. Wants to know if the second entry in the map, a list, has 'find' in it.

Comment: @pm100: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search the list that has the key "here" then do (this assumed you know that "here" entry really is there)

```
auto &here = adl_list["here"];
if (std::find(here.begin(), here.end(),"find") != here.end())
{
    std::cout << "found";
}
```

if it might not be there then do

```
auto &lookup= adl_list.find("here");
if(lookup != adl_list.end())
{
   auto &here = lookup.second;
   if (std::find(here.begin(), here.end(),"find") != here.end())
   {
     std::cout << "found";
   }
}
```